# Nameless requires in JSPM

Tags: javascript, jspm

Basic question, im trying to convert my webpack project to jspm, in which i load JS based on the site's current view, like this:

```
    var currentView = document.body.getAttribute('data-jscontroller');
    if ( currentView ) {
        var viewPath = './views/' + currentView;
        require( viewPath );
        App.Views[currentView].init();
    }
```

Unfortunately this returns an error:

```
es6-module-loader.js:7:26213
TypeError: Module ./views/home not declared as a dependency.
```

The contents of the file being required is a simple object that simply builds an object with event subscribers to the app functionality for the loaded view.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `require` are statically parsed so they won't allow js variables inside it. For those cases, there's `System.import`:

```
var currentView = document.body.getAttribute('data-jscontroller');
if ( currentView ) {
    var viewPath = './views/' + currentView;
    System.import(viewPath).then(function(){
       App.Views[currentView].init();
    });
}
```